# How to find most frequent value in SQL column and return that value?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, top-n

I was trying to do something like this:

```
select nume_produs
from incasari 
group by id
having count(nume_produs) =  max(count(nume_produs));
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  For instance, why are you aggregating by `id`?

Comment: because it's the id of the nume_produs. I have the table Table with columns id, product_id, product_name (nume_produs), amount, price, data collection

Comment: and I need to write a function for the most sold product of the month

Answer (score 4):

Do a GROUP BY. Order by count descending. Fetch the first row (highest count) only.

```
select nume_produs, count(*) as cnt
from incasari 
group by nume_produs
order by cnt desc
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

Answer (score 3):

For the most common value in the column:

```
select num_produs
from (select nume_produs, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by count(*)) as seqnum
      from incasari
      group by nume_produs
     ) i
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want multiple values in the event of duplicates, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

If you want the most common value *per id*, then add `partition by`:

```
select num_produs
from (select nume_produs, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by count(*)) as seqnum
      from incasari
      group by nume_produs
     ) i
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT       `nume_produs`,
             COUNT(`nume_produs`) AS `value_occurrence` 
    FROM     `incasari`
    GROUP BY `nume_produs`
    ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC
    LIMIT    1;
```

Increase 1 if you want to see the N most common values of the column.

Comment: Oracle database does not work with `LIMIT` so this query will fail.. You would need to use ROWNUM in Oracle or ANSI/ISO SQL standard FETCH

Comment: Backticks won't work with Oracle. Use ANSI SQL's double quotes instead, like `"nume_produs"`.

Comment: @jarlh - except that using double-quotes with mixed-case identifiers will hurl ORA-00942 if the table was not created like that, which I'm guessing is the case for the OP.

Comment: @srikanth - answers for questions tagged `[oracle]` should use Oracle RDBMS syntax, not MySQL (even though it's owned by ORCL corporation).  Also not MS SQL Server syntax even when the question is tagged `[sql]`.